# Setting IP address in Centos 7

Tags: centos, ssh, ip

I recently received a 64 core server for work. It has centos, SLURM and several things already installed. I can log into the server fine if I connect a keyboard. However, I need to rackmount it, and access it from a laptop.

I have been unable to ssh into it. When I try, it says password denied. When I check `var/log/secure/` it shows no record of attempted ssh logins, failed or successful.

When I try to check the IP address using `ip a` I get the following

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
   link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
   inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0f0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default glen 1000
    link/ether d4:5d:64:be:32:c2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: stuff
4: stuff
```

I expected to see the IP address in item 2, but it says DOWN. I am not sure how to change this or even, what I am missing?

Once the IP address is fixed, I would expect to be able to SSH in fine?

Comment: @A.B. I could start a new question, modifying this one isn't fair to John. The downside of starting a new question, is you are here, now, who knows when you will be there,

Answer (score 3):

The first thing that output indicates is that there's no cable connected (or if there is, the other end of the cable is not connected). That's what the `NO-CARRIER` bit indicates. The `DOWN` indicates that the interface has not been activated / configured by the OS. Once you fix those two things, you should see the machine on the network. Ensuring you can SSH in involves ensuring that the SSH daemon is enabled / started. This daemon is started by default on most, but not all, Linux distributions.

Comment: nitpicking: Actually the second DOWN means operstate down which is a consequence of the NO-CARRIER. The UP word near the NO-CARRIER means the OS administratively configured the interface UP (it's usually not possible to detect a NO-CARRIER without first bringing the interface (administratively) up).

Comment: @A.B. the cable was always connected... I fixed the network start/restart issue by deleting the ifcfg-eth0 I made when following google's advice since I have a different set of ethernet cards. however, SSH still doesn't work... I can ping the server, and I can ask it to ssh, but it denies password, and the attempt doesn't show up in /var/log/secure